# C# dynamic JSON serialization

Tags: c#, json

I'm calling an API to fetch a list of devices. In my model i have an attribute for list of devices:

```
public List<Device> device { get; set; }
```

But, if the API returns 1 device, it's returned as just a Device, not a list of devices with 1 device.

Is there any good way to have a dynamic deserialize? I don't want to have two different models, and parse the JSON programatically just to know which object to deserialize as.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ListDevicesByLabelModel>(responseText);
```

Comment: can you provide more of your code. it could be something else that is going on.

Comment: Where's the offending Json? If the API returns a single object instead of an array with one object ...

Comment: It's nestled, the device list is an attribute of an attribute etc..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685/how-to-handle-both-a-single-item-and-an-array-for-the-same-property-using-json-n)

Comment: Try using `SingleOrArrayConverter` from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685/how-to-handle-both-a-single-item-and-an-array-for-the-same-property-using-json-n

Answer (score 2):

The dynamic keyword is still great for deserializing JSON, I would recommend that you take a look on this question.

[Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object)

```
dynamic data = Json.Decode(responseText);
```

And then you've got a dynamic object to work with instead of needing 2 models.

Otherwise you could also have just one item in the List.